# How do I access the file system from a c++ library in Firefox OS

Tags: file-io, firefox-os, emscripten

I have built a c++ library that does lots of low level (read only) I/O, i.e. fsetpos, fread etc. This library is used by all implemenations of our app, i.e. iOS, android etc. We want to build a version of our app for Firefox OS, and found that you can't use native code in your apps there. I decided to use emscripten to work around this, and managed to interact with the library just fine, except that it couldn't find any files in firefox os. It expects to be handed a path to a directory with files in it.

Is this even possible? I need to be able to access the files directly from c++, and they are too large to hold in memory. I will always use just a small part of each file, and need to be able to jump around in the files fast. I haven't found any documentation for firefox apis that will work for me. The emscripten documentation suggests that NODEFS is the only way to do it, by mounting a data directory in NODEFS, but it doesn't look like it will work on firefox os. Another option would be to preload the data with the emscripten build, but the files are too large for that.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to a c library with a JavaScript.
The only way it's edit gonk with gaia for add your custom support to the library.
Or write a file and read it with javascript.